# Upload to SQL Server 2012 via ODBC dbWriteTable - Error "String data, right truncation" column type chr vs. nvarchar(50)

Tags: sql-server, r, database, data.table

I try to insert a data.table from R to SQL Server 2012 database:

```
library(data.table)
library(odbc)
library(dplyr)

upload.data <- data.table(readxl::read_excel(path = uploadfile.file, sheet = 
sheet_no, skip = skip_rows), col_names = TRUE)

odbcChannel <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "SQL")

dbWriteTable(odbcChannel, "Table_Name", upload.data, append = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE, row.names=FALSE, encoding = "latin1")
```

The columns in the data table are of type chr. The columns of the target table in SQL Server are of type `varchar(50)`.

My understanding is that chr would be uploaded as `varchar(255)`. Because of this I will get the error:

> Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) :
>   nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 22001: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation

How can I change the columns in R to match the specific needs of the table in my database?

If there is content in the column which would not fit into the database table I would like that the information gets cut away.

One solution: upload the data table into a new table into the server and than edit the types to match with:

```
dbSendStatement(odbcChannel,"ALTER  TABLE Table_Name
                             ALTER COLUMN Batch_Name Nvarchar(50)")
```

After this I could insert the data in the target table. But this seems quite complicated especially if every column in the database has a different type.

Best regards and my thanks,

HP

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this issue.

If I use the following code than I can define the field types and length:

```
sql.field.types <- list(Batch_Name = "nvarchar(50)")

dbWriteTable(odbcChannel, "Table_Name", upload.data, append = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE, 
                              row.names=FALSE, encoding = "latin1", field.types = sql.field.types )
```

This still yields me the error message if there is content in one of the columns in the data table which is longer as defined in the database.

But it is best to adjust the data in the data table with R to meet the requirements of the database. Therefore you always have a defined and    reproducible process.

Best Regards,

HP

Answer (score 1):

Have this same problem. Tried the suggested solution, but did not work.

One option is too truncate the data (not optimal) with

```
b <- upload.data[, lapply(upload.data, function(x) max(nchar(x), na.rm=TRUE)) > 240] %>% colnames()
upload.data[b] <- substr(upload.data[b], 1, 240)
```

where 240 an arbitrary max character length to use to cut strings.

Then, you can append the data

```
DBI::dbWriteTable(odbcChannel,
                        name = "Table_Name".
                        value = upload.data,
                        append = TRUE, overwrite = FALSE, 
                        row.names=FALSE, encoding = "latin1")
```

Would still be glad to hear alternative ways to avoid truncating the data!